# Java - does the collection always change when I get a value and change

Tags: java

I'm writing a program now in Java which is kind of like a server. I got a `MemberController`, in `MemberController` it gets `Members` from the database OR from the cache (to speed up process). This is an example of how it looks:

```
public class MemberController {

    private final TMap<Integer, Member> members;

    public MemberController() {
        this.members = new THashMap<>();
    }

    public Member getMemberByID(int id) {
        if (members.containsKey(id)) {
            return members.get(id);
        }

        // GET DATA FROM DB
        members.put(ID, MEMBER);
        return MEMBER;
    }
```

Now, `Member` contains a `BadgeController` object, which contains a `TMap` for the badges. Example of `Member`:

```
public class Member {
    // FIELDS OF MEMBER HERE
    private BadgeController badgeController;

    public Member(ResultSet set) {
        // SET FIELDS
    }

    public void InitOtherData() {
        badgeController = new BadgeController(id);
    }

    public BadgeController getBadgeController() {
        return badgeController;
    }
```

And `BadgeController`:

```
public class BadgeController {

    private final int memberId;
    private final TMap<String, Badge> badges;

    public BadgeController(int memberId) {
        this.memberId = memberId;
        this.badges = new THashMap<>();

        // LOAD FROM DB
    }

    public Badge getBadge(String code) {
        return badges.get(code);
    }
```

Now, I was wondering a few things (all actually refer to the same I guess):

1. If I get a `Member` from `members`, like `members.get(1)`, and I edit the object, like this:

   Member member = members.get(1);
    member.setId(1);

Will this edit the `id` inside the `TMap` as well? So if I do `members.get(1)` again, it has the updated value?

2. If I have the member from above, and I change a value of the `Badge`, for example I do:

`Member member = members.get(1);
 member.getBadgeController().getBadge('500Members').setActive(true);`

Will this result in true being printed?

```
System.out.println(members.get(1).getBadgeController().getBadge('500Members').getActive());
```

I hope my explaination is good enough. It's hard for me to explain it. I'm sorry.

Comment: Why don't you test it? That said, you're probably pre-optimizing, and opening a big can of worms: you'll now have to deal with obsolete data in the cache, concurrent access to a non-thread-safe mutable data structure, etc. Just use the database, it's fast.

Comment: I want to know if it always works. And it's complex to explain and complex to test. It goes MUCH deeper than just this.

Comment: Yes, it always works. No data structure will ever make copies of your objects. They just store references.

Comment: There is also a *problem* when you're *not* using a database, you're not persisting your changes, ie the effect of setting some attribute of a member you've loaded into memory is lost when your program ends. And databases have their own caching anyway.

Comment: @Bohemian Yes, but when the server is stopped / a member disconnects, it saves the changes in the database. Some things are pushed to the database immediately. That's not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Member member = members.get(1);` does not copy the object but just makes a shortcut (reference). Changing `member` affects the item in your set as well.

To create an effective copy you have to make your object inherit from the `Cloneable` interface and call the `clone()` method on it to get a copy.

Comment: And it doesn't matter how deep I go? For example, I make a reference, then I set the `BadgeController`, then I change something in the `badges` set, those changes are ALL made in the original `members` set?

Comment: @jean-françois-fabre i think that better will be to use a copy constructor :)

Comment: @ceph3us: you're right. I was about to mention that `clone()` is difficult to master because of the depth of the object/reference tree contained in the current cloned object.

Answer (score 1):

you need to **DEEP** copy object by:

- implementing clone interface
- create a copy constructor (simplest solution as clone)

examples:

```
    // simple copy constructor 
    public SomerController(SomeController original) {
         members = orginal.clone();
    }


    // more advanced  copy constructor 
    public SomeController(SomeController original) {
        Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries = orginal.members.entrySet();
        members = new HashMap<String,Class>();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Class>> iterator = entries.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, String> next = iterator.next();
            String key = next.getKey();
            // if class contains a collections ( maps, arrays ) 
            // you need to provide a copy here 
            // ensure to copy whole tree of references 
            Class value next.getValue();
            map.put(key,value);
        }
    }
```